# Capture Video without Third Party SDK's

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript, monobehaviour

I am trying to capture the game play and store it on local memory without using any third party sdk's. I tried [This Video Capture Script](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsholographic-videocapture.html) but i didn't get the recorded file even i don't know whether it's recording or not.

anybody please help me to complete the task. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well Manoj, for starters this scripts captures video feed from a webcam and the game itlsef. Also it does not work in the Editor. Helping you complete your task is not what stack exchage is for. Do your research, write your code and come back with a specific problem that you can not solve. Nobody wants to write your code for you.

Comment: May I ask why the restriction on SDKs? Using [Unity's own free Everplay plugin](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/add-ons/services/everyplay-16005) would almost certainly be simpler, faster, and quite likely higher quality/performance than attempting your own, and it's already cross-platform.

Comment: The plugin ll support only for few platforms. I am developing a game for all platforms.

Comment: Render your screen to RenderTexture. Get the texture, create png. From all the recorded images make video.

Comment: If i did like that means i ll lost the sound